# Complexity of computing $ABx$ depends on the order of multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, computational-complexity

To calculate $y = ABx$ where $A$ and $B$ are two $N\times N$ matrices and $x$ is an vector in $N$-dimensional space. there are two methods. One is to first calculate $z=Bx$, and then $y = Az$. This way takes roughly $2N^2$ multiplications. The other is to first calculate $C = AB$, and then $y=Cx$. This way, however, takes $N^3+N^2$ multiplications!

Am I correct on this? I do not understand why change of the order of the calculation introduces so much difference in the computation complexity.

Comment: I hope there is a good answer to this question, but I'll comment that the phenomenon has been studied pretty well, in some sense. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication) Wikipedia page.

Comment: You could also use this formula, but it's $2N^3$ multiplications! $$y_i = \sum_{jk} A_{ij} B_{jk} x_k $$

Comment: “$x$ is a $N\times 1$ vector...” please avoid saying things like that. $x$ is a vector in an $N$-dimensional space $V$, that. It so happens that such vectors can be represented by $N\times 1$ matrices, but it's good to make a conceptual distinction. (Basically, the matrix version describes a _function_ $\mathbb{R}\to V$, not just a vector in $V$.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout: Sure. Thank you for correction.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I like this question. I've seen the solution to efficiently calculating a chain of matrix multiplications in an algorithms class, but it's not very enlightening. I've always meant to think more about the problem because [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron) is interesting. So, let me try my hand at an explanation.

When you have an $N$ by $N$ matrix, it's a shorthand for describing a linear transformation from an $N$-dimensional vector space to itself. It does that by keeping track of where $N$ basis vectors get sent (these are the columns of your matrix).

Now, I'll just speak heuristically and it won't be very precise. I'll say that to write down a matrix, you just need to keep track of where $N$ linearly independent vectors get sent, not necessarily a basis. This is true, but all sorts of actual computational things depend on the exact basis (like actually writing down a vector, or doing standard calculations like $Bx$).

When you compute $AB$, you're keeping track of where $N$ linearly independent vectors get sent. But when you go on and use your freshly-computed $AB$ to compute $(AB)x$, you just care about where $1$ vector gets sent -- even though you went through all the trouble of keeping track of what $AB$ does to $N - 1$ other vectors!

Computing $A(Bx)$ is great, because at each step, it *only* pays attention to what's happening to the vectors you care about; it has no idea what happens to the other $N - 1$ linearly independent vectors, and so it only takes about one $N$th as much work as computing $(AB)x$.

While not exactly precise, I'd like to believe this is the *idea* behind why computing $A(Bx)$ is more efficient than $(AB)x$, which is what I think you are after.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for your clear explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you are correct, this is used a lot in engineering. Two popular cases:

1. Knowing $AB$ and trying to find $A$ and $B$ which individually contain larger percent 0s than $AB$ multiplied together does. Usually called factoring or "fast transforms". If we lose enough non-zero numbers we can save calculations in this way.
2. Precomputing $AB$ if we have individual $A$ and $B$ and want to calculate $ABv$ for lots of $v$:s. This should be done if $AB$ is simpler than $A$, $B$ separately.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the step $C = AB$ takes more multiplications as we are multiplying two matrices, the first method you mention does not do this.

Each step $z=Bx$ and $y = Az$ contributes $N^2$ multiplications only, as it is a vector multiplied by a matrix and not a matrix multiplied by a matrix.